# ADC Charge up time

Tags: operational-amplifier, adc, voltage-divider, potentiometer

I have a potentiometer transducer with a 5V swing, which goes into a divider, then a voltage follower, then a RC filter and finally the microcontroller (see schematic below).

My issue is even though the pot input voltage is steady the op-amp takes some time to reach the correct adc. So for example, if I have 3.850 volts out of the pot at power on, the output voltage from the op-amp should be 2.568V. But its initially 2.400 roughly (could be lower) but eventually rises up over the course of a few minutes. My question is what could be causing the slow charge up and how can I improve it?

[image]

Comment: How are you measuring the output voltage of the op-amp? If the circuit is built on a breadboard, have you tried re-seating all the components?

Comment: I measured at both pin 10 and pin 8, so going into and out of the op-amp. I have some prototype boards made from JLC and it appears to be happening on both of them so cold-solder join and such is unlikely.

Comment: If it is a potentiometer transducer, why the very large resistances? 500k and 1M

Comment: The inputs of any unused amplifiers should be tied to ground to avoid possible oscillation which can interfere.

Comment: I don't see any time constants that would reflect minutes. Even with those huge resistor values in your divider. One thing that comes to mind when seeing "minutes" and not seeing anything in the circuit that plausibly accounts for it is *temperature*. That does tend to operate on that order of time. That doesn't mean I can tell you what it is. But I might try a heat gun on this just to see what happens.

Comment: The resistor values i took from a STM32F7 layout example. I suppose they dont need to be that big, though I cant see how that accounts for the slow adc rise. I am going to try some temperature testing then , cant hurt.

Comment: Did you make a test thingy before a PCB?

Comment: Yes I modded a NucleoF7 with the same hardware and did not see this issue. The only issue I had was the read/cycle rate was too fast, giving a lower reading.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to go check the datasheet more thoroughly.

I suspect you might be out of spec attempting to drive 3.850 volts with a Vdd of 5V (The TI datasheet for Voh claims only 3V Minimum and 3.8 Typical and Figure 29 suggests so as well).  A quick test would be to increase the Vdd to 6 or 7V and see if that improves things.

If you must have 5V Vdd, you probably need to go hunt down a rail-to-rail op-amp.

Good luck.